# Acer KB-0759 Keyboard Problems

Tags: windows, keyboard

The space bar acts as the return key
The Right shift key launches shutdown
The Right ctrl key launches sleep
The right arrow key displays /
and the b key shows bv
and the m key shows mn
I changed the computer it was connected too, no luck
any idea whats causing it.

Comment: What is "changed the computer it was connected too" ?

Comment: connected the keyboard to a different computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given that's it's the same problem on a different PC, I'd say the keyboard is broke and having googled the model number, it's probably best to just drop the 8 bucks to buy another.  Unless you simply want to tinker.